# How can the limit of this $F(x,y)$ is $0$ when it is taken along $y=x^2$ or $ x=y^2$?

Tags: calculus, limits

> Find $$\lim_{(x,y) \to (0,0)}\frac{3x^{2}y}{x^{2}+y^{2}}$$ if it
>   exists.

From my textbook, it said that the limits along the parabolas $$y=x^{2}\text{ and } x=y^{2}$$ also turn out to be 0.

I couldn't figure out why, as if we set $$x=y^{2}$$, for example

then $$\lim_{(x,y) \to (0,0)}\frac{3x^{4}}{x^{2}+(x^{2})^{2}}$$

$$\lim_{(x,y) \to (0,0)}\frac{3x^{4}}{x^{2}+x^{4}}$$
$$\lim_{(x,y) \to (0,0)}\frac{3}{0+1}$$
then the answer is supposed to be $3$?  right?

Comment: $\dfrac{3x^2x^2}{x^2+(x^2)^2}=\dfrac{3x^2}{1+x^2}\to0$

Comment: No. see answers

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A smaller (in magnitude) denominator means a larger number in magnitude (given numerator are the same).

$$|\frac{3x^2y}{x^2+y^2}| \leq |\frac{3x^2y}{x^2}|=|3y| \to 0$$

Then conclude with squeeze theorem.

Your error is that $\frac{x^2}{x^4}=\frac{1}{x^2} \to \infty$ not zero.

So the denominator goes to infinity and hence your limit goes to $0$ as claimed in the book.

Answer (score 3):

On $y=x^2$ we have
$$
\frac{3x^2y}{x^2+y^2}=\frac{3x^4}{x^2+x^4}=
\frac{3x^4}{x^2(1+x^2)}=\frac{3x^2}{1+x^2}
$$
which has limit $0$ when $x\to0$.

On $x=y^2$ we have
$$
\frac{3x^2y}{x^2+y^2}=\frac{3y^5}{y^4+y^2}=\frac{3y^5}{y^2(y^2+1)}
=\frac{3y^3}{y^2+1}
$$
which again has limit $0$ for $y\to0$.

Answer (score 2):

Note that

$$\lim_{x\to \infty}\frac{3x^{4}}{x^{2}+x^{4}}=3$$
but
$$\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{3x^{4}}{x^{2}+x^{4}}=\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{3x^{2}}{1+x^{2}}=0.$$